# RegisterRawInputDevices function usage

Tags: c++, winapi

I have several questions about `RegisterRawInputDevices()` function. I mean obviously it is for registering raw input device but the real question is how can I use that registered raw input device?

Can I monitor `WM_INPUT` messages with this device? I couldn't find any examples.

On MSDN every parameter of function is input parameter I didn't see any output parameter for monitoring.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You must catch `WM_INPUT` in the `WindowProc` callback function.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633573(v=vs.85).aspx

And retrieve the `RAWINPUT` structure, which contains the raw input from the device.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645562(v=vs.85).aspx

Maybe this link will help you. Just remember that the questioner in this link went wrong. You need to read comment to get the right way. 
[Get WM_INPUT from Unity window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38921656/get-wm-input-from-unity-window)